# Sending application on Google Play beta testing

Tags: android, google-play

I want to send the application to the beta testing Google Play. My question is: how to do in the application so that at the end of testing people could update the app and enjoy working version. How to organize it will be in the API and in the application? Share your experiences, links or something else. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing to do within the application or over some API. Right in the **Developer console** you're given the ability to **promote** your uploaded version **to** the **Beta or Production** stage. See the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot for promoting app to Beta etc.]

So as soon as your app is ready for the masses, just push it to Prod and everyone will be able to download and/or update it.

Comment: And if the beta tester has disabled auto-update? How to get it to update the version of the application?

Comment: You can't force an application update. You can only remind the user to update via a Dialog or something, but checking and showing this is more a Backend related story rather than something that has anything to do with Google Play / Android. ;)

Comment: My question was directed specifically to the fact to find out in what form to download the app for beta testing in Google Play. I want to lay out the application for the use of 100 people for example. 100 beta testers. I am a newbie and so I want to figure out how to do it correctly

Comment: So do you know how to setup Alpha/Beta-Tests in the Developer Console? If not this link might be useful: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: Yes, I have already published an alpha version for the staff of my office. The problem is that to get them to update the application I can. But for beta testing it is necessary to invent something. I do not want to screw up